# reverse the way readdir works (last file first)

Tags: perl, readdir

I have a directory which contains n files, all matching the pattern
`/^\d\d\d\d$/` through which I go with a `while (my $file = readdir ($DIR) ) { ... }` to avoid reading the whole directory to RAM at once.
In this loop I count the files (excluding directories and files not named accordingly) and pick out five files, starting at a specified point, and read the first two lines of each file into an array.

My actually two questions are:

1. Is it possible to start the loop at the last file in the directory, starting at the file with the largest filename and going "back"?
   (I guess every OS would return these files in order 0000 -> 0001 -> 0002 ...)
2. Since this would be way easier, how bad would it be to just read the whole directory in an array in comparison to going through the whole list one by one?

Full code block:

```
while ( my $f = readdir ($DIR) ){

    print "checking " .  $f . "\n";
    next unless -f ($dir . "/" . $f);
    next unless $f =~ /^\d\d\d\d$/;

    $c++;

    if ( $c >= $index && $c <= $index + 4 ){
        open (my $ITM, "<", "$dir/$f") or die "Opening file $f in $dir failed:$!\n";
            my $headline = <$ITM>; my $first_p = <$ITM>;
        close $ITM;

            chomp ($headline, $first_p);
            push (@content, $headline, $first_p); 

        print $f . " was checked succesfully!\n";
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The formatting problems were caused by you using `<pre><code>` (inline HTML) tags instead of just indenting (which is the Markdown syntax for code blocks).

Comment: I would recommend doing the pattern check before the `-f` check ... That way, you'd avoid an expensive `stat` call for names that don't match the pattern.

Comment: Technically speaking your regex matches a lot of strings that you probably didn't intend to match; e.g. `$` allows for a trailing newline in the name, while `\d` matches any Unicode digit (not just 0-9). I'd use `/\A\d{4}\z/a` (or `/\A[0-9]{4}\z/` if your perl doesn't have `/a` yet).

Comment: If you do end up reading them in an array (based on the answers below), you could get just the 4 character filenames as: my @files = <????> and then check for them being numeric.

Comment: @deepakg Good point. You could even do `glob('[0-9]' x 4)` to just get numeric names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. File systems generally return directory entries in an unpredictable order. They won't be sorted alphabetically. (Except possibly on Windows? Not sure.)
2. Even if you have a million files in that directory, that's just a "mega". So if each name takes 10 bytes to store, that's only 10 MB of RAM. OK, there's some overhead in Perl's internal data structures, but you're almost certainly going to have fewer names than a million. So I'd say it's not bad at all.

Comment: Not even on Windows. See [FindNextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428(v=vs.85).aspx): *The order in which the search returns the files, such as alphabetical order, is not guaranteed, and is dependent on the file system. If the data must be sorted, the application must do the ordering after obtaining all the results.*

Comment: @SinanÜnür Thanks, that's good to know. It does say "*With the NTFS file system ... the names are usually returned in alphabetical order*", which is probably what I remember seeing in my tests, but of course it's not guaranteed.

Comment: So if I want to have (reliably) one file and the four "following" files I have no choice but to read them in an array and sort them? Thanks for the NTFS-hint, I was wondering why it was working for me all the time...

Comment: @user7183174 That's definitely the easiest way. There are fancier algorithms for selecting e.g. the 5 smallest or 5 biggest elements from a list in linear time and constant memory, but that's probably more effort than it's worth.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Yep, got that, just wanted to clarify why I didn't notice this problem so far

Answer (score 0):

Use `glob()` to get a list of the files.

```
my @files = grep /\/\d{4}$/, glob( "$dir/*" );
```

You can then sort them in whatever order you want.